# html to pdf conversion using HTML2PDF class

Tags: php, html, pdf

I am trying to convert some html content to pdf using HTML2PDF class. But I am getting the below error

> Fatal error: Uncaught ERROR nÂ°4
> File :
>   /html2pdf/_class/parsingHtml.class.php
> Line : 120
> HTML code
>   invalid, the tags are not closed in an orderly fashion.

Code I am using is below :

```
<?php
        require_once('html2pdf.class.php');
        $filename = 'test.html';
        $report=file_get_contents($filename);
        $content = '';
        $content .="<page  footer='page' backtop='20%' backbottom='13%' backleft='1%' backright='1%'>";
        $content .= $report;
        $content .="</page>";

        ob_get_clean();
        $pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','en','true','UTF-8');
        $pdf->WriteHTML($content,false);
        ob_end_clean();
        $pdf->Output('Demographic_Analysis.pdf');
        exit;
?>
```

Please help

Comment: I faced this error once. Is your html file clean??? i.e, have you closed all the tags in a proper way?? or semantically correct... Can you post your html file content as well?

Comment: Actually dynamic content (based on certain criteria like date filtering,drop down selection etc )is writing to the html page which I am later converting to pdf.

For most of the cases its working properly. But in few cases,getting the above error.So I don't think there is issue in html tags.